# Why is mysql not using index when available

Tags: mysql, indexing, database-performance

I have a query that is really slow and im not sure why, there are indexes for every join field.

This is my query:

```
    SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN
            arrears_action.executed IS NULL
                OR arrears_action.executed != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
        THEN
            'No action'
        ELSE DATE_FORMAT(arrears_action.planned, '%d %M %Y')
    END,
    CASE
        WHEN
            arrears_action.executed IS NULL
                OR arrears_action.executed != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
        THEN
            NULL
        ELSE IF(DATEDIFF(NOW(), arrears_action.planned) >= 0,
            DATEDIFF(NOW(), arrears_action.planned),
            NULL)
    END,
    customer.id AS customer_id,
    customer.customer_number AS cif_number,
    arrears_application.id AS arrears_application_id,
    person.id AS person_id,
    person.fullname,
    account.account_number,
    CONCAT(branch.branch_id,
            product.code,
            SUBSTRING(contract.loan_number, - 9, 9)) AS loan_account,
    payment.principal_amount_outstanding,
    arrears.amount_in_arrears,
    arrears.days_in_arrears,
    balance.account_balance_available,
    product.code AS product_code,
    division.name AS division_name,
    coll_customer_status.name AS customer_status,
    loan_status.name AS loan_status
FROM
    cregora_cregora.base_cregora_loancontract_inarrears_data AS arrears 
        INNER JOIN
    cregora_cregora.base_cregora_loancontract_data AS contract ON contract.id = arrears.loancontract_id 
        INNER JOIN
    cregora_cregora.base_cregora_loancontract_payment_data AS payment ON payment.loancontract_id = contract.id
        INNER JOIN
    cregora_cregora.base_cregora_nmb_product_class_data AS product ON product.id = contract.product_class
        INNER JOIN
    cregora_cregora.base_cregora_account_data AS account ON account.id = contract.account_id
        INNER JOIN
    cregora_cregora.base_cregora_customer_data AS customer ON customer.id = account.customer_id
        INNER JOIN
    cregora_cregora.base_cregora_person_data AS person ON person.id = customer.type_of_customer_id
        INNER JOIN
    cregora_base.system_organization_division AS division ON division.id = contract.loan_branch
        INNER JOIN
    cregora_cregora.base_cregora_nmb_branch_data AS branch ON branch.id = division.entity_instance_id
        INNER JOIN
    cregora_cregora.base_cregora_account_balanceinfo_daily_data AS balance ON balance.account_id = account.id
        LEFT JOIN
    cregora_cregora.base_cregora_arrears_applications_data AS arrears_application ON arrears_application.loan_contract_number = contract.loan_number
        LEFT JOIN
    cregora_cregora.base_cregora_arrears_action_data AS arrears_action ON arrears_action.arrears_application_id = arrears_application.id
        LEFT JOIN
    cregora_cregora.base_cregora_collection_applications_data AS coll_application ON coll_application.arrears_application_id = arrears_application.id
        LEFT JOIN
    cregora_cregora.base_cregora_collection_customer_statuses_data AS coll_customer_status ON coll_customer_status.id = coll_application.collection_customer_status_id
        LEFT JOIN
    cregora_cregora.base_cregora_arrears_loan_contract_statuses_data AS loan_status ON loan_status.id = arrears_application.loan_contract_status_id
        LEFT JOIN
    cregora_cregora.base_cregora_arrears_application_statuses_data AS arrears_status ON arrears_status.id = arrears_application.arrears_application_status_id
WHERE
    contract.loan_branch IN (46)
        AND (coll_customer_status.id IN ('1' , '2',
        '3',
        '5',
        '6',
        '7',
        '8',
        '9',
        '10',
        '11',
        '12',
        '13',
        '15',
        '16',
        '17',
        '18',
        '19',
        '20',
        '21',
        '22',
        '23')
        OR coll_customer_status.id IS NULL)
        AND (loan_status.id IS NULL
        OR loan_status.id IN ('1' , '2', '3', '4', '5'))
        AND arrears.amount_in_arrears > '1'
GROUP BY arrears_application.id
ORDER BY arrears.days_in_arrears DESC , person.fullname
```

This is the output of the EXPLAIN :
[image: explain]
Why is mysql not using any of the indexes of the contract table (third line of explain, type-> ALL, possible keys ->PRIMARY,account_id,loan_branch,product_class key->empty?

Thnx in advance

Comment: Can you make your explain a bit more readable please. It may not be using an index for the simple reason that it's not needed! Why are you concerned about it is the query slow? If so give the timing and also indicate number of rows in each table

Comment: used a pic instead of text output, the contract table is not using any index as you can see. It is doing a full table scan. The nr of records im not sure yet because im still importing the actual test data but there are a lot. On production this query will run for 5 min or so. Additional note: when removing the group by and order by clause the query drops to below a second

Comment: pointless doing any sort of analysis while a large import operation is already running

Comment: yes i know but other teammembers have done an analysis as well so we know the query runs that long and it is importing to my local db btw not the production so that is not it

Comment: What is the output of `show variables like 'optimizer_search_depth';`?

Comment: output of optimizer_search_depth = 62

Comment: Try `ALTER TABLE contract ADD INDEX (loan_branch,account_id,loan_number);` and report how it affects the performance (give before and after benchmarks.) Be sure to run each query twice in a row, discarding the first result, to avoid the buffer cache contaminating the results. Also report if the EXPLAIN changes after adding the index.

Comment: well performace i will post once i have the actual test data, but the explain did not change other than listing the newly created index amongst the possible key values but still leaving key itself empty and using "type" ALL

Comment: The problem is that MySQL optimiser is affected by the number of rows. If you have only a few records in the contracts table, then the optimiser may opt for a full table scan even if there is an index it could use. When you have millions of records in the table, the optimiser will definitely prefer an index over a full table scan.

Comment: ok that could be an issue with the limited testdata im running the explain on now so i will produce it again when i have my full testdata. But i ran the explain extended and the filtered column for the culprit contract index shows a number of 75.86, which indicates that when using the index +- 75% will get filtered on my current data when using the index so that indicates that the index should be used does it not?

Comment: Some interesting columns of `EXPLAIN` were chopped off.  Try again.

Comment: Try  `optimizer_search_depth = 1`.

Comment: What percentage of  `contract` has `loan_branch IN (46)`?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE contract`

Comment: Is there only one "division" and only one "branch"?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that the arrears_application_data table was left joined but also grouped by. This resulted in a significant performance drop